# Where should I put this query to avoid having to run it multiple times?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a simple calendar page, and I need to populate it with a list of available dates.

I get the list as follows:

```
 List<DateTime> availableDates = (from d in sb.GetDaysWithAvailableSlotsByLocation(3)
                                         select d.Date).ToList<DateTime>();
```

However, it looks like the calendar renders before this function is called in the Page_load as I need to put this query in my code twice to make it work:

```
    public partial class BookYourSlot : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    public SlotBooker sb = new SlotBooker();
    public List<DateTime> availableDates = new List<DateTime>();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        List<DateTime> availableDates = (from d in sb.GetDaysWithAvailableSlotsByLocation(3)
                                         select d.Date).ToList<DateTime>();
        DateTime firstAvailable = availableDates.Min();

        calSlotBooker.VisibleDate = firstAvailable;



    } 


    protected void calSlotBooker_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
    {
       List<DateTime> availableDates = (from d in sb.GetDaysWithAvailableSlotsByLocation(3)
                                        select d.Date).ToList<DateTime>();


        if (!(availableDates.Contains(e.Day.Date)) || (e.Day.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday) || (e.Day.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday))
        {
            e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Silver;
            e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
            e.Cell.ToolTip = "Unavailable";
        }

    }
}
```

This seems highly inefficient as it is calling the availableDates query every time a cell renders.

How do I do this once on the page, and make it accessible to the calendar control's DayRender event?

Comment: can you add an if statement that checks a flag 'alreadyrendered'?

Answer (score 0):

Store the list as a page property:

```
List<DateTime> AvailableDates {get; set;}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AvailableDates = (from d in sb.GetDaysWithAvailableSlotsByLocation(3)
                                     select d.Date).ToList<DateTime>();
    DateTime firstAvailable = AvailableDates.Min();
    calSlotBooker.VisibleDate = firstAvailable;
} 

protected void calSlotBooker_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if (!(AvailableDates.Contains(e.Day.Date)) || (e.Day.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday) || (e.Day.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday))
    {
        e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Silver;
        e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
        e.Cell.ToolTip = "Unavailable";
    }
}
```

> it looks like the calendar renders before this function is called in the Page_load

I doubt that.  Rendering happens after loading, so unless this particular control does something weird (like Render after `Init` but before `Load`) `Load` should be called first.

My guess is you were trying to access a *local* variable of `Page_Load` from the `Render` method, which would not work, but not because of the order of events..

Comment: Quite right! I was reinitialising the list on page load, and hadn't made availableDates a page property

Answer (score 0):

What happens is, that you are hiding the declaration of `availableDates`. In `Page_Load` you are not using the field declared on `Page`, but the one declared locally in the scope of the method (the same is in `calSlotBooker_DayRender`). Just change the local declaration of variable `List<DateTime> availableDates` only to `availableDates`.

```
public List<DateTime> availableDates;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    availableDates = (from d in sb.GetDaysWithAvailableSlotsByLocation(3)
                                     select d.Date).ToList<DateTime>();
    DateTime firstAvailable = availableDates.Min();
    calSlotBooker.VisibleDate = firstAvailable;
}
```

Comment: Even if he fixed this; he'd still be performing the query on each postback.